# How to override default invoice pdf styling file in magento2.2.7

Tags: magento2

I added the logo to the default pdf file and  i want to change the width and height and pdf height width how to do that?

Comment: do you want to overide default pdf file, right?

Comment: yes i want to override the default pdf

Comment: I added answer, Kindly check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do following things.

1. create `di.xml` file into your custom extension at following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\adminhtml\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Vendor\Extension\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
</config>
```

2. now create the `Invoice.php` file at the following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Order\Pdf;

class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
    public function getPdf($invoices = [])
    {
        // DO YOUR LOGIC HERE
    }

}
```

Comment: In  the default font style is roobato i want to change font style montserrat in pdf file how to do that?

Comment: That you need to add particular tag, and that apply there.

Comment: If answer help you, please accept as solution and upvote, so it help other into community.